# how can i define a Hotkey to edit the text in an AutoCompleteBox?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, setfocus

I'm using the WPF AutoCompleteBox control, i need to define a hotkey to begin the edition of its content immediatelly. I have this:

```
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.F))
            autoCompleteBox2.Focus();
```

That code set the focus but the edition doesn't begin. I have to manually press the Left or Right key and then i could use it. I've search in his properties and in the web but I still don't found the answer.

That control is part of the WPF Toolkit. http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Comment: Are you saying you can't see the caret?

Comment: are you talking about this control http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/WPFAutoCompleteBox/ ?

Comment: @mihajlv exactcly, it takes the focus in a different way, it get selected but the edition do not begin. The problem also arise to get out of the control, I need to press two times the tab key because with the first the edition end and it get selected, then I need to press again and the focus moves to the following control.

Comment: @klm_ no. I'm talking of the AutoCompleteBox found in http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue in what I am coding right now, this is how I solved it, it is a little tricky:

To move the focus away:

```
 if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            this.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

---

```
autoCompleteBox2.Focus();
```

worked for me, you need to have set:

```
autoCompleteBox2.Focusable = true;
```

if it still doesn't work have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx), it should help.